# How can I access copied mongodb folder

Tags: mongodb

I just got copied database folder(literally copy and paste) of mongodb. 
Actually, I'm beginner of mongodb and have a lot of problem to access copied database. 
Could you give me any advice?

Comment: what do you mean by copied database ? is that a collection dump using mongodump ? or you take the whole dbpath folder ?

Comment: The latter one. Whole dbpath folder.

Answer (score 0):

To start the database with the new directory - you can do the following:

1. Change dbpath in config: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath), then restart mongod service
2. Run single mongod instance like "mongod --dbpath /data/db".
   If you use WireTiger engine - "mongod --dbpath /data/db --storageEngine wiredTiger"

Comment: I'm not saying start with a new directory. I want to start with copied whole dbpath folder. 
Could you give me any idea??

Comment: Change "/data/db" to the path of your copied db folder